# Eclipse could not resolve Maven paths

Tags: eclipse, maven, buildpath

I have my local m2 repo set to `/Users/ratha/.m2/repository`.

I built maven projects using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and imported to my eclipse workspace. To resolve build paths, i set the build path by setting Libraries/M2_REPO variable. But, all my java files could not locate the jars which are in my local maven repository.

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use? Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: Maven 3.0.5 and Eclipse  Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)

Comment: Don't use `mvn eclipse:eclipse´ anymore better use the import as Maven project in Eclise Luna, cause there is a very good support via `m2e` in Luna.